# select from mysql view into outfile

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble to select data from view in mysql to outfile.

```
SELECT *
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/test.txt'
FROM test_view;
```

I'm getting the following error:

> ERROR 1356 (HY000) at line 1: View 'test_view' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them

When I only use the following in sql, it's fine.

```
SELECT *
FROM test_view;
```

I'm using mysql version: 5.1.69

Thanks.

Comment: The error message is quite self explaining, isn't it? Do you or the definer have the right to query all columns and tables used in the view?

Comment: @fancyPants Although you are right in a way, this doesn't provide a real solution. I just had the same issue even when using the root user, which has all grants/privileges. Still this leads to the correct issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue even though I was using the root user on my database.
Sadly I cannot explain why a simple `SELECT` query works, but fails when using a `SELECT INTO OUTFILE`.

There may be other solutions and may be this is not working out for you, but I wanted to shared my solution anyway, since no approved answer exists.

In my case I check the views definition and found settings, that were also visible in the frm-file: `definer_user=<other username>`, but in the view the security setting was set to `Definer` and not `Invoker`.

In my case it made no sense that a random person from the support team was set as a definer. I had no idea what the SQL security changes in detail, so I just changed the definer of the view to `root@%`.

**After setting the definer of the view to `root@%` (obviously you can set other hosts if required) the statement works fine for me.**

Answer (score -3):

MySQL provides an easy mechanism for writing the results of a select statement into a text file on the server. Using extended options of the INTO OUTFILE nomenclature, it is possible to create a comma separated value (CSV) which can be imported into a spreadsheet application such as OpenOffice or Excel or any other applciation which accepts data in CSV format.

Given a query such as

```
SELECT order_id,product_name,qty FROM orders
```

which returns three columns of data, the results can be placed into the file /tmo/orders.txt using the query:

```
SELECT order_id,product_name,qty FROM orders
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/orders.txt'
```

This will create a tab-separated file, each row on its own line. To alter this behavior, it is possible to add modifiers to the query:

```
SELECT order_id,product_name,qty FROM orders
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/orders.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Comment: And in which way does this answer the question? No one asked for a quick tutorial. And btw, it sounds like you copy&pasted this from somewhere. Name the source if you did.